# Proving Lebesgue measure is translation invariant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that for any set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $\lambda_n(A)=\lambda_n(A+\beta)$; in other words, if we translate a set the translated set will have the same Lebesgue measure as the initial set.

Attempt: By definition of Lebesgue measure, we have
\begin{equation}
\lambda_n(A):=\inf\left\{\sum_i(b_i-a_i):A\subset\bigcup_i[a_i,b_i)\right\}.
\end{equation}

Note that $A\subset\bigcup_i[a_i,b_i)$ is equivalent to $A+\beta\subset\bigcup_i[a_i+\beta,b_i+\beta)$, and using our definition for Lebesgue measure above we have (using the fact that $(a_i+\beta)-(b_i+\beta)=(a_i-b_i)$)

\begin{equation}
\lambda_n(A+\beta):=\inf\left\{\sum_i(b_i-a_i):A+\beta\subset\bigcup_i[a_i+\beta,b_i+\beta)\right\}.
\end{equation}

But I cannot see how to demonstrate the equivalence to $\lambda_n(A)$ using just the definition.

Comment: Its looks fine, however the proof you wrote is for $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ bacuse you use intervals. If you replaces those with open cubes (the ones used it for the definition of Lebesgue measure) then the proof will be fine for $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You'll want $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as well

Answer (score 1):

Well you can prove that $\lambda_n (A) \leq \lambda_n(A+\beta)$, since on the right hand side you are taking an infimum over a potentially smaller set of sums of countable collections of covering sets. The same reasoning shows that $\lambda_n (A+\beta) \leq \lambda_n((A+\beta) - \beta)$.

Comment: The same reasoning works for any linear isometry (the point is that linear isometries preserve volumes of cubes and are invertable).